# The background color in each todo-section does not cover the entire row when the checkbox is selected. The color doesn't reach behind the checkbox

Tags: html, css

The background color in each todo-section does not cover the entire row when the checkbox is selected. The background color does not reach behind the checkbox. This is one of the todo-sections in my html from the form. It's one of 13 set up the exact same way. Please click the [enter image description here] link above for a visual of what I'm trying to convey.

Below is the associated CSS. The issue that I'm having is that when the box is checked, the line strikes through the text like it's supposed to and the associated color appears in the background as well. However, the color isn't reaching behind the checkbox. Screenshot provided above in link.

```css
.todo-section [type=checkbox]:checked+label {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  background-color: #D7B99E;
}

.todo-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="todo-section">
    <input type="checkbox" id="todo1" name="todo1" value="ID"><label for="todo1" class="checked"> Please bring picture ID and insurance card on the day of your 
    procedure.</label> </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to select a parent in CSS, however, there's still some "magic" to achieve this if you work with the positioning of the elements.

```css
.todo-section [type=checkbox]:checked+label {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  background-color: #D7B99E;
}

input {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
}

label {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-indent: 30px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.todo-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  position: relative;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="todo-section">
    <input type="checkbox" id="todo1" name="todo1" value="ID"><label for="todo1" class="checked"> Please bring picture ID and insurance card on the day of your
      procedure.</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

While [support is lacking currently](https://caniuse.com/css-has), in the future, the [`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) pseudo-class does what you want.

In this case, it will target the entire `.todo-section`, rather than just the `label` as the original selector did.

Note that version 105+ of Chrome supports the selector, and I would expect other Chromium-based browsers to follow suit soon as well. In fact, my copy of Microsoft Edge (Version 103.0.1264.77 (Official build) (64-bit)) renders the following snippet correctly, even though technically it shouldn't be able to...

```css
.todo-section:has([type=checkbox]:checked) {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  background-color: #D7B99E;
}

.todo-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="todo-section">
    <input type="checkbox" id="todo1" name="todo1" value="ID"><label for="todo1" class="checked"> Please bring picture ID and insurance card on the day of your 
    procedure.</label> </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also use grid and set both elements inside the same cell (alike absolute but in the flow), padding and  margin can be used to align elements and keep their content away from each others.

here is an example:

```css
.todo-section [type=checkbox]:checked+label {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  background-color: #D7B99E;
}

.todo-section {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}


/* grid layout VS absolute */
/* base needed */
.todo-section {
  display: grid;
}

.todo-section>* {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1
}

/*demo makeup */

.todo-section {
  margin:1em 5em;
  background:#bee
}


input {
  margin: auto;
  margin-inline-start: 0.5em;  /* will follow the document direction */
  position: relative;  /*To keep it on top  
  or use  
  transform:scale(1) ; 
  or any transform value that is set to defaut */
  }

label {
  padding-inline-start: 2em;  /* will follow the document direction */
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="todo-section">
    <input type="checkbox" id="todo1" name="todo1" value="ID">
    <label for="todo1" class="checked"> Please bring picture ID and insurance card on the day of your 
    procedure.</label>
  </div>

  <div class="todo-section" dir="rtl">
    <input type="checkbox" id="todo2" name="todo1" value="ID">
    <label for="todo2" class="checked"> Please bring picture ID and insurance card on the day of your 
    procedure.</label>
  </div>
</form>
```